# Flutter / Kotlin method channel file delete fails

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel

I have a flutter application that fetches images from internal storage, the permission for read/write are already handled using storage_path plugin in flutter.

Also write permission is given at AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The methodchannel code looks like this:
filename example: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20201116-224238_Pixel_Launcher.png

```
    private val CHANNEL = "com.rs.gallery/gallery"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "Delete") {
                val file = call.argument<String>("file")
                Log.d("method channel", file)
                val f = File(file)
                if (f.exists()) {
                    val res: Boolean = f.delete()

                    Log.d(file, res.toString())
                } else {
                    Log.d(file, "NOT FOUND")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output of the delete method is false and unable to delete the file.
What am I missing? Or is the permission for deleting file from internal storage to be handled separately?

Comment: does your app asks for permission?

Comment: the storage_path plugin asks only for read permission. I then wrote the write permission in the manifest. but still does not work.

Comment: even if you have them in your manifest, you have to ask the permission, the permission pop ups? remember, use permission handler plugin on the pub

Comment: I had tried the permission_handler plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). There is option for only "storage" permission, which is the same as the permission requested by storage_path plugin.

Comment: storage path asks the user for permission?

Comment: The storage_path plugin asks only for read permission of media files. I just tried the permission_handler plugin with request to storage permission, it shows permission is already granted, and does not prompt for permission, but still unable to delete file. (FYI: I am testing on physical device on Android 11).

Comment: storage permission is both read/write, why are you doing file operations on native when you can do the same in flutter

Comment: ok, I try flutter and get back.

Comment: I get this error when I perform file.delete() `Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot delete file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20201116-224238_Pixel_Launcher.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

Comment: no file exist at the path, may be path is wrong!!

Comment: I get the same error with all the files.

Comment: if it was permission problem the Exception would have been different your paths are wrong, try to list the files in `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/`

Comment: Here is the summary. On android 11, the images are displayed but unable to delete. On android 10, the images are NOT displayed, says permission denied. Compile SDK 29, min SDK 21